# Intersection Algorithm between 3D Polygon and A Cube

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I need a quick algorithm to check whether a 3D Polygon (a list of 3D coordinates that are co-planar, given a list of points in counter-clockwise or clockwise order, the polygon can be convex or concave, in other words, it must be simple polygons non-intersecting itself) and a **cube**(given the lower-left and top-right coordinates, the cube edges align with the X/Y/Z axis) intersects.

Is there any quick way to do this? thanks.. I've google for a few pages, but not yet found something exactly the same.

Many thanks..

**EDIT**
Sorry, when I said 'Box', I meant 'Cube'.
A cube is defined as two corner points. lower-left and top-right (or the other pair, doesn't matter).

Comment: what have you tried so far? what's the language of choice? looks more like a Programmers question than SO

Comment: it doesn't matter which language, i can implement the idea later. I havn't got a clear idea on how to do this...

Comment: I can see one problem with your requirements - a list of 3D coplanar coordinates does not define one unique polygon.  Does your program assume that the polygon is the convex hull of these points?

Comment: Also, by "Box" do you mean a 2D square or a 3D box?

Comment: Also, what does "lower-bottom" mean, since lower and bottom mean the same thing?

Comment: What about the polygon?  How do we know which polygon is defined by your points?  Do you connect the points in list order?  Or do you take the convex hull of the points?  Or something else?

Comment: Also, 2 points do not uniquely define a 3D box.  Imagine holding the box by those two points - you can freely rotate the box, yielding infinitely many boxes that fit those 2 points.

Comment: the polygon is simple polygon (non intersecting itself), the order can be given in clockwise or counter-clockwise, yes. you are right, the 3D cube is defined by two points and the cube edges are aligning with the axies.

Comment: I'm thinking the box is the same one I asked about [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/251127/name-of-region-defined-by-two-points-in-higher-dimensions).

Answer (score 2):

1. Check for polygon-polygon intersection between your polygon and each side of the box.
2. Check if any of the polygon's points are inside the box.

Comment: @MC - I believe the OP is talking about a 2D polygon in 3D space, not a polyhedron.

Comment: Seems I got confused at some point. Your answer is probably sufficient then.

Answer (score -1):

Here are some tests that should work

1. Check if 1 or more of the polygon points inside the box, but not all of them.
2. Check if any of the polygon's edges intersect with the edges of the box.
3. Check if any of the polygon's faces intersect with the faces of the box.

If any of the above hold then they intersect. All area listed as it's probably worth the trouble to test them in order as extracting the faces and calculating if they intersect may not be do able in linear time.

Comment: I don't think you need to do #1 if you are doing #2.  Also, the box could pass right through the middle of the polygon without touching any points or edges.

Comment: yes.. this seems first idea to me, but I was stuck knowing that the polygon can wrap the box without touch it.

Comment: #3 is also insufficient.  The polygon could be completely inside the box.

Comment: I think your answer and mine are pretty close now.  I'm not sure why you have the "but not all of them" restriction on #1?

Comment: It's really up to the OP as to whether if the polygon being completely inside the box counts as intersecting. Basically a question of if the box is solid or not. If it's solid then if any points are inside of it, then they intersect. If it isn't solid, then it only matters if the faces of the box cut through the polygon. Which don't happen if the polygon is inside of the box.